# How To get "IDST" and "Store" fields on this View?

Tags: sql-server

i have and view that contain many tables it works fine but i can't get some  fields  i need from there table (stores) - i got them 'NULL' and i can't know what is the problem ?

**Sorry For Log Query**

```
WITH    ProductSales
      AS ( SELECT   p.IDPr ,
                    p.Product ,
                    od.IDST ,
                    ISNULL(SUM(od.Quantity / pu.UnitQty), 0) AS TotalSalesQty
           FROM     dbo.OrdersSales AS oh
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersSalesDetails AS od ON oh.OrdersID = od.OrdersID
                    INNER JOIN dbo.products AS p ON od.IDPr = p.IDPr
                    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductUnits AS pu ON p.IDPr = pu.IDPr
           WHERE    ( oh.OrdersKind = N'مبيعات' )
                    AND ( pu.UnitType = N'رئيسية' )
           GROUP BY p.IDPr ,
                    p.Product ,
                    od.IDST
         ),
    ProductFirstStock
      AS ( SELECT   p.IDPr ,
                    dbo.OrdersPurchasesDetails.IDST ,
                    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.OrdersPurchasesDetails.UserInputQty
                               * p.PurshPrice), 0) AS TotalFirstStocAmount ,
                    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.OrdersPurchasesDetails.UserInputQty), 0) AS TotalFirstStockQty
           FROM     dbo.OrdersPurchases
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersPurchasesDetails ON dbo.OrdersPurchases.OrdersID = dbo.OrdersPurchasesDetails.OrdersID
                    INNER JOIN dbo.products AS p ON dbo.OrdersPurchasesDetails.IDPr = p.IDPr
           WHERE    ( dbo.OrdersPurchases.Kind = N'اول المدة' )
           GROUP BY p.IDPr ,
                    dbo.OrdersPurchasesDetails.IDST
         ),
    ProductPurchases
      AS ( SELECT   p.IDPr ,
                    OrdersPurchasesDetails_3.IDST ,
                    ISNULL(SUM(OrdersPurchasesDetails_3.ItemTotal), 0) AS TotalPurchasesAmount ,
                    ISNULL(SUM(OrdersPurchasesDetails_3.UserInputQty), 0) AS TotalPurchasesQty
           FROM     dbo.OrdersPurchases AS OrdersPurchases_3
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersPurchasesDetails AS OrdersPurchasesDetails_3 ON OrdersPurchases_3.OrdersID = OrdersPurchasesDetails_3.OrdersID
                    INNER JOIN dbo.products AS p ON OrdersPurchasesDetails_3.IDPr = p.IDPr
           WHERE    ( OrdersPurchases_3.Kind = N'مشتريات' )
           GROUP BY p.IDPr ,
                    OrdersPurchasesDetails_3.IDST
         ),
    ProductSalesReturn
      AS ( SELECT   p.IDPr ,
                    od.IDST ,
                    ISNULL(SUM(od.Quantity / pu.UnitQty), 0) AS TotalSalesRetQty
           FROM     dbo.OrdersSales AS oh
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersSalesDetails AS od ON oh.OrdersID = od.OrdersID
                    INNER JOIN dbo.products AS p ON od.IDPr = p.IDPr
                    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductUnits AS pu ON p.IDPr = pu.IDPr
           WHERE    ( oh.OrdersKind = N'مردودات مبيعات' )
                    AND ( pu.UnitType = N'رئيسية' )
           GROUP BY p.IDPr ,
                    od.IDST
         ),
    ProductPurchasesReturn
      AS ( SELECT   p.IDPr ,
                    OrdersPurchasesDetails_2.IDST ,
                    ISNULL(SUM(OrdersPurchasesDetails_2.UserInputQty), 0) AS TotalPurchasesRetQty ,
                    ISNULL(SUM(OrdersPurchasesDetails_2.ItemTotal), 0) AS TotalPurchasesReturnAmount
           FROM     dbo.OrdersPurchases AS OrdersPurchases_2
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersPurchasesDetails AS OrdersPurchasesDetails_2 ON OrdersPurchases_2.OrdersID = OrdersPurchasesDetails_2.OrdersID
                    INNER JOIN dbo.products AS p ON OrdersPurchasesDetails_2.IDPr = p.IDPr
           WHERE    ( OrdersPurchases_2.Kind = N'مردودات مشتريات' )
           GROUP BY p.IDPr ,
                    OrdersPurchasesDetails_2.IDST
         ),
    ProductPurchasesTransfer
      AS ( SELECT   p.IDPr ,
                    OrdersPurchasesDetails_1.IDST ,
                    ISNULL(SUM(OrdersPurchasesDetails_1.UserInputQty), 0) AS TotalPurchasesTransQty
           FROM     dbo.OrdersPurchases AS OrdersPurchases_1
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersPurchasesDetails AS OrdersPurchasesDetails_1 ON OrdersPurchases_1.OrdersID = OrdersPurchasesDetails_1.OrdersID
                    INNER JOIN dbo.products AS p ON OrdersPurchasesDetails_1.IDPr = p.IDPr
           WHERE    ( OrdersPurchases_1.Kind = N'تحويل' )
           GROUP BY p.IDPr ,
                    OrdersPurchasesDetails_1.IDST
         ),
    ProductSalesTransfer
      AS ( SELECT   p.IDPr ,
                    od.IDST ,
                    ISNULL(SUM(od.UserInputQty), 0) AS TotalSalesTransQty
           FROM     dbo.OrdersSales AS oh
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersSalesDetails AS od ON oh.OrdersID = od.OrdersID
                    INNER JOIN dbo.products AS p ON od.IDPr = p.IDPr
           WHERE    ( oh.OrdersKind = N'تحويل' )
           GROUP BY p.IDPr ,
                    od.IDST
         )
SELECT  s.IDST ,
        s.Store,
        p2.IDPr ,
        p2.Product ,
        pu.UnitName ,
        ISNULL(( ISNULL(F.TotalFirstStockQty, 0)
                 + ISNULL(B.TotalPurchasesQty, 0)
                 + ISNULL(RS.TotalSalesRetQty, 0)
                 + ISNULL(PT.TotalPurchasesTransQty, 0) )
               - ( ISNULL(RP.TotalPurchasesRetQty, 0)
                   + ISNULL(A.TotalSalesQty, 0)
                   + ISNULL(ST.TotalSalesTransQty, 0) ), 0) AS Stock ,
        CAST(ISNULL(AVG(( ISNULL(B.TotalPurchasesAmount, 0)
                          + ISNULL(F.TotalFirstStocAmount, 0)
                          - ISNULL(RP.TotalPurchasesReturnAmount, 0) )
                        / NULLIF(ISNULL(B.TotalPurchasesQty, 0)
                                 + ISNULL(F.TotalFirstStockQty, 0)
                                 - ISNULL(RP.TotalPurchasesRetQty, 0), 0)),
                    0) AS DECIMAL(18, 3)) AS AvgPurchasePrice ,
        ISNULL(( ISNULL(F.TotalFirstStockQty, 0)
                 + ISNULL(B.TotalPurchasesQty, 0)
                 + ISNULL(RS.TotalSalesRetQty, 0)
                 + ISNULL(PT.TotalPurchasesTransQty, 0) )
               - ( ISNULL(RP.TotalPurchasesRetQty, 0)
                   + ISNULL(A.TotalSalesQty, 0)
                   + ISNULL(ST.TotalSalesTransQty, 0) ), 0)
        * CAST(ISNULL(AVG(( ISNULL(B.TotalPurchasesAmount, 0)
                            + ISNULL(F.TotalFirstStocAmount, 0)
                            - ISNULL(RP.TotalPurchasesReturnAmount, 0) )
                          / NULLIF(ISNULL(B.TotalPurchasesQty, 0)
                                   + ISNULL(F.TotalFirstStockQty, 0)
                                   - ISNULL(RP.TotalPurchasesRetQty, 0), 0)),
                      0) AS DECIMAL(18, 3)) AS StockValue
FROM    dbo.products AS p2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductSales AS A ON A.IDPr = p2.IDPr
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductFirstStock AS F ON p2.IDPr = F.IDPr
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductPurchases AS B ON p2.IDPr = B.IDPr
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductSalesReturn AS RS ON p2.IDPr = RS.IDPr
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductPurchasesReturn AS RP ON p2.IDPr = RP.IDPr
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductPurchasesTransfer AS PT ON PT.IDPr = p2.IDPr
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductSalesTransfer AS ST ON ST.IDPr = p2.IDPr
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Stores AS s ON s.IDST = A.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = B.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = F.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = PT.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = RP.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = RS.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = ST.IDST
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ProductUnits AS pu ON pu.IDPr = p2.IDPr
WHERE   pu.UnitType = N'رئيسية'
GROUP BY F.TotalFirstStockQty ,
        B.TotalPurchasesQty ,
        RS.TotalSalesRetQty ,
        RP.TotalPurchasesRetQty ,
        A.TotalSalesQty ,
        PT.TotalPurchasesTransQty ,
        ST.TotalSalesTransQty ,
        p2.IDPr ,
        p2.Product ,
        s.IDST ,
        s.Store ,
        pu.UnitName
ORDER BY p2.IDPr
```

the output data i got all products in each store in one row but as you can see IDST is NULL and Store Is NULL too

[image]

so please how can i fix it ?

Comment: Sorry, I doubt anyone here is gonna read through all that code

Comment: So What That mean please ?

Answer (score 0):

Without dissecting your entire query, I would take a harder look at

```
SELECT  s.IDST ,
        s.Store,
...
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Stores AS s ON s.IDST = A.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = B.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = F.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = PT.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = RP.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = RS.IDST
                                           AND s.IDST = ST.IDST
```

You're doing a left outer join on a series of left outer joins.  Perhaps you could pick one... perhaps p2

Comment: when i use And on l still got Null Values